# Showing that $K$ is dedicable is equivalent show that $Acc_{GNC}$ is decidable

Tags: context-free

1. If $K$ is a context-free language, then $K$ is a decidable language.
2. $\text{Acc}_{\text{CFL}} = \{〈G, w〉: G \text{ is a context-free grammar and G can generate } w\}$ is decidable.

I am a bit confused. For me, showing that $K$ is dedicable is equivalent show that $Acc_{GNC}$ is decidable. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both statements are correct and thus are "equivalent" logically, even though it doesn't really mean anything. However, I will light the difference between the two statements.

### Statement 1

We need to show there **exists** a TM that decides $K$. That is, for a different $K$ we can find a different turing machine.

### Statement 2

We need to find **one** TM that is capable of deciding any language given its grammer. That is, here for different $G$'s we still use the same TM. In this sense, the second statement is stronger than the first, and it implies it.

Comment: So $L(K)  \subset L(\text{Acc}_{\text{CFL}})$, but not $L(K)  \supset L(\text{Acc}_{\text{CFL}})$. I think I am wrong.

Comment: Not precisely. $\{G|G \text{ is a grammer for } K\}\times L(K) \subset L(Acc_{CFL})$, but not vice versa